# Add Command to Menu Entry in 13.10 to convert images to JPG

Tags: nautilus

It is possible to add a Menu Entry that when I click a picture it says "convert to JPG" and executes this command?

convert -format jpg {The right click file}

Because normally when I want to attach screenshots they are very heavy cause they are stored in PNG.

It will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your input, with that info I found the solution, will post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dobey for the input, with that I found a way to do it:

**~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Convert to JPG**

```
#!/bin/bash
## Convert to JPG Script 0.1
## Dependencies: imagemagick

mogrify -format jpg -quality 70 -resize 80% $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
```

Perfect for attach screenshots in the work mail, reduced the screenshots from 1.4M to 90K, and quality is not important cause it is just to show something fast to work buddies.

Thanks!!!